# something to read to understand ordinary differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Could you recommend me please any books on ordinary differential equations where I will find the information about Cauchy problem with parameter and Cauchy operator?

Comment: There are ODE textbooks to teach undergraduate courses from, and there are more expositional works, many focusing on applications of one kind or another.  It will help Readers respond more cogently if you edit the Question to give more context for your request.

Comment: @hardmath I want to read about  Cauchy problem with parameter and Cauchy operators

Comment: If you need to use this information for *ordinary differential equations*, presumably you can be more specific about your motivation. That would be very helpful.  A parameter could be incorporated into Cauchy conditions in various ways, and solving the resulting problems would depend on how the parameter appears there.  For a brief introduction to the meaning of *Cauchy operator* for a *system of ordinary differential equations*, see this [Encyclopedia of Math article](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cauchy_operator), where three texts are listed as references.